# angular-bootstrap-calendar horizontal scrolling issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling, angular-bootstrap

I'm using [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://mattlewis.me/angular-bootstrap-calendar/) and am having a difficult time getting horizontal scrolling to work properly. The plugin's demo page has the same issue I'm experiencing.

To reproduce the issue, visit the demo page, click the Day view, and add a bunch of events so that they stack in columns horizontally. Once the horizontal scrollbar appears, scroll to see the event containers cut off (notice the sudden loss of styling behind the newly created events).

Screenshot of issue in the demo:
[image: Demo scrolling issue]

And the issue gets worse when vertical scrolling is introduced:
[image: My issue]

I'm assuming that this has something to do with the way Bootstrap renders its columns, but I haven't been able to solve this issue yet. Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

**Edit:**
Here is a [video of the issue](http://tinypic.com/r/21nqx5v/8)

Comment: your link is not working..` angular-bootstrap-calendar `